# Start date and End date of two weeks within a date range in PHP

Tags: php, date

I want to get the start date  and end date of two weeks within a date range in PHP.

Week start = Sunday and week end = Saturday

ie)for example if date range is

> $start = '2013-01-01'  and
>    $end ='2013-02-28'

**Required Result**

> Start Date-->2013-01-01 End Date -->2013-01-12
>   Start Date-->2013-01-13 End Date -->2013-01-26
>   Start Date-->2013-01-27 End Date -->2013-02-09
>   Start Date-->2013-02-10 End Date -->2013-02-23
>   Start Date-->2013-02-24 End Date -->2013-02-28

**Code**

```
  <?php
$st = '2013-01-01';
$et ='2013-02-28';
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($st));
$end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($et));
$end_date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($et. '+ 6 days'));

$weekfrom = array();
$weekto = array();

for($date = $start_date; $date <= $end_date1; $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date. ' + 14 days')))
{

    $week =  date('W', strtotime($date));
    $year =  date('Y', strtotime($date));
    $from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}+1")); //Returns the date of monday in week
    if($from < $start_date) $from = $start_date;
    $to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}-6"));   //Returns the date of sunday in week
    if($to > $end_date)
     {
        $to = $end_date;       

     }
    if($from < $to)
    {
    array_push($weekfrom,$from);
    array_push($weekto,$to);
    }

}
$n = count($weekfrom);

for($i = 0;$i<$n;$i++)
{
  echo "Start Date-->".$weekfrom[$i];
  echo " End Date -->".$weekto[$i]."\n";
}


?>
```

**Current Result**

> Start Date-->2013-01-01 End Date -->2013-01-05
>   Start Date-->2013-01-13 End Date -->2013-01-19
>   Start Date-->2013-01-27 End Date -->2013-02-02
>   Start Date-->2013-02-10 End Date -->2013-02-16
>   Start Date-->2013-02-24 End Date -->2013-02-28

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/H0vIdNn0)

In the current result the start date is correct.But the issue is within the end date. Help me to find the issue

Comment: What is the pattern on which you base difference between start and end date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change to this one...

```
$to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}-6 + 1 week"));
```

See **[Codepad](http://codepad.org/WP6dDnqX)**

Answer (score 0):

for the first day:

```
if is Sunday == true
 today
else
 strtotime('last sunday');
```

for the last day:

```
if is Saturday == true
 today
else
 strtotime('next saturday');
```